# Bootstrap media query design issue

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

Sorry, this might be a very beginner question but I can't get my head around it,

I have been supplied designs with the widths below:

S- 320px
M - 768px
L - 992px
XL - 1920px

But the media queries they are using are below:

```
@media (min-width: 576px)
@media (min-width: 768px)
@media (min-width: 992px)
@media (min-width: 1200px)
```

I am not sure how to match the designs to the media queries, am I missing something super simple and obvious?

I apologise if so!!

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend to use some kind of css-precompiler like sass.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

you can change the configuration of your bootstrap-"theme" if you overide the variables of the variables.scss file. i your case these:

```
$screen-xs:                  480px !default;
$screen-xs-min:              $screen-xs !default;
$screen-phone:               $screen-xs-min !default;

$screen-sm:                  768px !default;
$screen-sm-min:              $screen-sm !default;
$screen-tablet:              $screen-sm-min !default;

$screen-md:                  992px !default;
$screen-md-min:              $screen-md !default;
$screen-desktop:             $screen-md-min !default;

$screen-lg:                  1200px !default;
$screen-lg-min:              $screen-lg !default;
$screen-lg-desktop:          $screen-lg-min !default;

$screen-xs-max:              ($screen-sm-min - 1) !default;
$screen-sm-max:              ($screen-md-min - 1) !default;
$screen-md-max:              ($screen-lg-min - 1) !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways (something like bootstrap is your friend), but based on the media queries you've mentioned, you can use these in your css as such:

```
# All your generic CSS here...

# Custom width CSS follows:
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .class {
    color:#000
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .class {
    color:#fff
  }
}

etc
```

In this simple example, `.class` would have the color #000 anything above 992px wide, and color #fff anything above 1200px wide.

As the 1200px media query is after the 992px media query, it superseeds it.

You can also use max-width, such as:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
# your CSS here
}
```

This is useful is you just want custom css on smaller screens, which is quite common when you have 'different' designs for phones etc.

And also make a range such as:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1150px) {
# your CSS here
}
```